# User and associated Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created an twiiter like app, where friends can post, but i want a include the name of the person who created the post in the list showing all the post.

here is my code

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create(:message => params[:message])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
        format.js
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Message failed to save."
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
      end
    end
  end
end
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, of course, that the 'user has many posts' association is set, and the user model has a 'username' field, you can do this in your view :

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it does has all you said, but i  get the error message `undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass` do i need to place anything in the post controller

Comment: This means that your post is not attached to a specific user, thus the association is nil. To avoid getting the error you can change the line to '<%= post.user.try(:username) %>'

Comment: `<%= div_for post do %>
  <p><b>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</b></p>
  
  <p><%=post.message%></p>
  
  

  

<% end %>`

Comment: @SpyroP, is there a way to do it from the controller and just place the variable in the view, my view is stated above